# Acentos en JAVA String

Tags: java, regex, str-replace, caracteres

Hola mi duda es saber si existe alguna expresión regular para quitar caracteres especiales de un string, ignorando acentos y ñ.

Es decir que el string sea algo así:

> //Hola Mundo(\) buen día##

El resultado buscado después de la expresión regular:

> Hola Mundo buen día

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

prueba con lo siguiente:

```
"//Hola Mundo(\\) buen día##".replaceAll("[^ \\p{L}]+", "")
```

La expresión regular:

```
[              # Un caracter que
 ^             # *no*
               # es ninguno de lo siguiente:
     _         #   - espacio (uso un guión bajo aquí para que se vea)
     \\p{L}    #   - cualquier caracter tipo letra (incluye letras unicode)
]              # Fin del aglutinador de posibles caracteres
+              # El conjunto de caracteres anterior, repetido una o más veces
               # esta repetición no es necesaria porque usamos replaceAll, pero
               # al tenerlo aquí es un poco más eficiente.
```